# Pass string parameters into click binding while retaining default params in Knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I'd like to pass arguments in to functions called on click, while retaining the default args. The issue is in the Hops part. I tried to make the `remove<this>` functions more clean with:

```
self.removeItem = function(item, name){
        self[name].destroy(item);
}
```

and

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: function() { $root.removeItem($data, "hops") }, visible: $root.hops.countVisible() > 1">Delete</a>
```

I have tried passing `$data, event, "hops"` also. I went based on [Knockout.js - passing parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14180876/knockout-js-passing-parameters) but I want to access the current element (the hop, grain, or yeast I'm deleting) while also giving the string of the array to delete from.

```js
ko.observableArray.fn.countVisible = function(){
    return ko.computed(function(){
        var items = this();

        if (items === undefined || items.length === undefined){
            return 0;
        }

        var visibleCount = 0;

        for (var index = 0; index < items.length; index++){
            if (items[index]._destroy != true){
                visibleCount++;
            }
        }

        return visibleCount;
    }, this)();
};

function Hop(data) {
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name || "");
    this.amount = ko.observable(data.amount || "");
    this.time = ko.observable(data.time || "");
    this.use = ko.observable(data.use || "Boil");
}

function Fermentable(data) {
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name || "");
    this.pounds = ko.observable(data.pounds || "");
    this.ounces = ko.observable(data.ounces || "");
    this.weight_unit = ko.observable(data.weight_unit || "oz");
    this.milling_preference = ko.observable(data.milling_preference || "Milled");
}

function Yeast(data){
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name || "White Wine");
}

function TaskListViewModel() {
    // Data
    var self = this;

    self.recipe_name = ko.observable("");
    self.hops = ko.observableArray([new Hop({}), new Hop({})]);
    self.fermentables = ko.observableArray([new Fermentable({name: 'test'}), new Fermentable({})]);
    self.yeasts = ko.observableArray([new Yeast({})]);
    self.hops_uses = ko.observableArray(['Boil', 'Dry Hop']);
    self.weight_units = ko.observableArray(['oz', 'lb']);
    self.milling_preferences = ko.observableArray(['Milled', 'Unmilled']);
    self.yeast_groups = ko.observableArray(
        [
            {category: 'Danstar', yeasts: ['Danstar 1', 'Danstar 2']},
            {category: 'Fermentis', yeasts: ['West Coast', 'American Saison', 'White Wine']},
            {category: 'White Labs', yeasts: ['White 1', 'White Saison']},
        ]
    );

    self.addFermentable = function(){
        self.fermentables.push(new Fermentable({}))
    }

    self.addYeast = function(){
        self.yeasts.push(new Yeast({}));
    }

    self.addHop = function(){
        self.hops.push(new Hop({}));
    }

    self.removeFermentable = function(fermentable){
        self.fermentables.destroy(fermentable);
    }

    self.removeYeast = function(yeast){
        self.yeasts.destroy(yeast);
    }

    self.removeHop = function(hop){
        self.hops.destroy(hop);
    }

    self.removeItem = function(item, name){
        self[name].destroy(item);
    }

    self.prepareJSON = function(){
        object = {
            fermentables: self.fermentables(),
            hops: self.hops(),
            yeasts: self.yeasts(),
        }
        return object
    }

    self.saveRecipeData = function(){
        var data_to_send = ko.toJSON(self);
        var recipe_data = ko.toJSON(self.prepareJSON());
        alert("This is the data you're sending (universal Javascript object notation):\n\n" + recipe_data)
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/receive-recipe",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: data_to_send,
            success: function(data){
                console.log("Success! Saved the recipe");
            }
        });
    }


}
ko.applyBindings(new TaskListViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <h2>Fermentables</h2>
        <div data-bind="foreach: fermentables">
            <label>Name:</label>
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: name"/>
            <label>Amount:</label>
            <input style="width: 45px;" type="number" min="0" data-bind="value: pounds"/> lb
            <input style="width: 55px;" type="number" min="0" data-bind="value: ounces"/> oz
            <label>Milling preference: </label>
            <select data-bind="options: $root.milling_preferences, value: weight_unit">
            </select>
            <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeFermentable, visible: $root.fermentables.countVisible() > 1">
                Delete
            </a>
            <br><br>
        </div>

        <input data-bind="click: addFermentable" type="button" value="Add Fermentable" />
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <h2 class="">Yeast</h2>
        <div data-bind="foreach: yeasts">
            <span>Yeast Brand Filter:</span>
            <select id="yeast-brand-select">
                <option value="">-Any-</option>
                <option value="Danstar">Danstar</option>
                <option value="White Labs">White Labs</option>
                <option value="Wyeast">Wyeast</option>
                <option value="-">Others</option>
            </select>
            <br/>
            <span>Yeast Variety:</span>
            <select id="yeast-variety-select" style="width:325px" data-bind="value: name">
                <option value="-"> - </option>
                <!-- ko foreach: $root.yeast_groups -->
                    <optgroup data-bind="attr: {label: category}">
                        <!-- ko foreach: yeasts -->
                            <option data-bind="value: $data, text: $data"></option>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </optgroup>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </select>
            <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeYeast, visible: $root.yeasts.countVisible() > 1">Delete</a>
            <br><br>
        </div>
        <br>
        <input data-bind="click: addYeast" type="button" value="Add Yeast"/>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <h2 class="">Hops</h2>
        <div data-bind='foreach: hops'>
            <label>Hop:</label> <input type="text" data-bind="value: name" >
            <label>Amount:</label>
            <input type="number" data-bind="value: amount" maxlength="6"> oz

            Time: <input type="text" data-bind="value: time" >
            Min.
            Use:  <select data-bind="options: $root.hops_uses, value: use"></select>

            <a href="#" data-bind="click: function() { $root.removeItem($data, "hops") }, visible: $root.hops.countVisible() > 1">Delete</a>

            <br><br>
        </div>

        <br>

        <input data-bind="click: addHop" type="button" value="Add Hop" />
    </div>

    <p>
        <button data-bind="click: saveRecipeData">Save recipe</button>
    </p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried with this code and it worked -

```
self.removeItem = function(item, name) {    
    name.remove(function(hop){
        return hop.name === item.name;
    });
    console.log(name());
    console.log(self.hops());   
}
```

Also change the binding for deleting like so -

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: function() { $root.removeItem($data, $root.hops) }, visible: $root.hops.countVisible() > 0">Delete</a>
```

And similarly for *fermentables* and *yeasts*.

I would suggest you to have some unique property associated with each row that you are adding so that it can be the matching criterion inside of the `self.removeItem` function, because as I can see, two records can have the exact same data which can cause ambiguity as to which item to remove from the array.

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/L89hu82y/)