# Return data from $.ajax to use later

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, knockout.js, django-rest-framework

I need to set `yeast_options` on my viewmodel in knockoutjs. I am serving the data correctly, but cannot access it with an ajax call. Ajax is not used the way I'd expect. I want to use functions to return what they create, and ajax is requiring to use a "success" function, which is not setting data onto my `yeast_options` attribute:

```
        self.get_yeasts = function(){
            console.log('in get_yeasts...')

            // var this_data = null;

            var onSuccess = function(data){
                alert("It worked!");
                alert(data);
                alert(self);
                console.log(data);
                // var this_data = data;
                self.yeast_options = data;
                return data;
            }

            var onError = function(error){
                alert("oops");
            }

            var data = $.ajax({
              dataType: "json",
              url: "http:/127.0.0.1:8000/api/items/yeasts",
              success: onSuccess,
              error: onError,
            });

            // });
            console.log("about to return the data");
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data.responseJSON);
            // debugger;
            return this_data;
        }
```

I've tried several different ways, like returning data from the success function, setting `self.yeast_options` within the success, and nothing will get the data to it

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    ko.observableArray.fn.countVisible = function(){
        return ko.computed(function(){
            var items = this();

            if (items === undefined || items.length === undefined){
                return 0;
            }

            var visibleCount = 0;

            for (var index = 0; index < items.length; index++){
                if (items[index]._destroy != true){
                    visibleCount++;
                }
            }

            return visibleCount;
        }, this)();
    };

    function Hop(data) {
        this.name = ko.observable(data.name || "");
        this.amount = ko.observable(data.amount || "");
        this.time = ko.observable(data.time || "");
        this.use = ko.observable(data.use || "Boil");
    }

    function Fermentable(data) {
        this.name = ko.observable(data.name || "");
        this.pounds = ko.observable(data.pounds || "");
        this.ounces = ko.observable(data.ounces || "");
        this.weight_unit = ko.observable(data.weight_unit || "oz");
        this.milling_preference = ko.observable(data.milling_preference || "Milled");
    }

    function Yeast(data){
        var self = this;
        var permanent_yeast_options = data.yeast_options;
        self.name = ko.observable(data.name || "-");
        self.current_filter = ko.observable("-Any-");
        self.yeast_groups_individual = ko.computed(function(){
            if (self.current_filter() !== "-Any-"){
                var options = _.filter(data.yeast_options, function(option){
                    return option.category === self.current_filter();
                });
                return options;
            } else{
                    return permanent_yeast_options;
                }
            }
        );
        self.yeast_categories = ko.observableArray();
        ko.computed(function(){
            var starter_list = ['-Any-'];
            var categories = _.pluck(permanent_yeast_options, 'category');
            var final = starter_list.concat(categories);
            self.yeast_categories(final);
        })
    }

    function TaskListViewModel() {

        var self = this;
        // debugger;
        self.dd = function(variable, varName) {
            var varNameOutput;

            varName = varName || '';
            varNameOutput = varName ? varName + ':' : '';

            console.log(varNameOutput, variable, ' (' + (typeof variable) + ')');
        };

        self.get_yeasts = function(){
            console.log('in get_yeasts...')

            // var this_data = null;

            var onSuccess = function(data){
                alert("It worked!");
                alert(data);
                alert(self);
                console.log(data);
                // var this_data = data;
                self.yeast_options = data;
                return data;
            }

            var onError = function(error){
                alert("sad panda");
            }

            var data = $.ajax({
              dataType: "json",
              url: "http:/127.0.0.1:8000/api/items/yeasts",
              success: onSuccess,
              error: onError,
            });

            // });
            console.log("about to return the data");
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data.responseJSON);
            // debugger;
            // return this_data;
        }

        // defaults
        self.hops_uses = ko.observableArray(['Boil', 'Dry Hop']);
        self.weight_units = ko.observableArray(['oz', 'lb']);
        self.milling_preferences = ko.observableArray(['Milled', 'Unmilled']);
        self.brew_methods = ko.observableArray(['Extract', 'Mini-Mash', 'All Grain', 'Brew-in-a-bag']);

        self.recipe_name = ko.observable("");
        self.brew_method = ko.observable("Extract");
        self.batch_size = ko.observable("5");
        self.beer_style = ko.observable("");
        self.boil_time = ko.observable(60);

        self.hops = ko.observableArray([new Hop({}), new Hop({})]);
        self.fermentables = ko.observableArray([new Fermentable({name: 'test'}), new Fermentable({})]);
        self.yeast_options = self.get_yeasts();
        console.log(self.yeast_options);
        self.yeasts = ko.observableArray([new Yeast({yeast_options: self.yeast_options})]);
        self.addFermentable = function(){
            self.fermentables.push(new Fermentable({}))
        }

        self.addYeast = function(){
            self.yeasts.push(new Yeast({yeast_options: self.yeast_options}));
        }

        self.addHop = function(){
            self.hops.push(new Hop({}));
        }

        self.removeFermentable = function(fermentable){
            self.fermentables.destroy(fermentable);
        }

        self.removeYeast = function(yeast){
            self.yeasts.destroy(yeast);
        }

        self.removeHop = function(hop){
            self.hops.destroy(hop);
        }

        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40501838/pass-string-parameters-into-click-binding-while-retaining-default-params-knockou
        self.removeItem = function(item, name){
            name.remove(function(hop){
                return hop.name === item.name;
            });
        }

        self.name_filter = function(the_array){
            var items = _.filter(the_array, function(item){
                return item.name() !== "" && item.name() !== "-";
            });
            return items;
        }

        self.amount_filter = function(the_array, countable_fields){
            var items = _.filter(the_array, function(item){
                var count = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < countable_fields.length; i++){
                    var this_number = +item[countable_fields[i]]();
                    count = count + this_number;
                }
                return count > 0;
            });
            return items;
        }

        self.dual_filter = function(the_array, countable_fields){
            items = self.name_filter(the_array);
            items = self.amount_filter(items, countable_fields);
            return items;
        }

        self.purify_yeasts = function(yeasts){
            var final_yeasts = [];
            for (i = 0; i < yeasts.length; i++){
                var item = yeasts[i];
                var object = {name: item.name};
                final_yeasts.push(object);
            }
            return final_yeasts;
        }

        self.prepareJSON = function(){
            object = {
                fermentables: self.dual_filter(self.fermentables(), ['pounds', 'ounces']),
                hops: self.dual_filter(self.hops(), ['amount']),
                yeasts: self.name_filter(self.purify_yeasts(self.yeasts())),
                recipe_name: self.recipe_name(),
                brew_method: self.brew_method(),
                batch_size: self.batch_size(),
                beer_style: self.beer_style(),
                boil_time: self.boil_time(),
            }
            return object;
        }

        self.saveRecipeData = function(){
            var recipe_data = ko.toJSON(self.prepareJSON());
            alert("This is the data you're sending (universal Javascript object notation):\n\n" + recipe_data)
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8000/receive-recipe",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                method: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: recipe_data,
                success: function(data){
                    console.log("Success! Saved the recipe");
                }
            });
        }

        self.my_to_json = function(object){
            return JSON.stringify(object, null, 4);
        }
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new TaskListViewModel());
</script>
```

The server gives

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def serve_yeasts(request):
    """
    Serve up some yeasts
    """
    data = [
        {'category': 'Danstar', 'yeasts': ['Danstar 1', 'Danstar 2']},
        {'category': 'Fermentis', 'yeasts': ['West Coast', 'American Saison', 'White Wine']},
        {'category': 'White Labs', 'yeasts': ['White 1', 'White Saison']},
    ]

    return Response(data=data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: try setting context property of ajax call to your viewmodel. the you can access it in your success func as 'this'. :)

Comment: I don't understand what that means

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: "*Ajax is not used the way I'd expect*" - because you're missing the "A" part of "AJAX".  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = $.ajax({
              dataType: "json",
              url: "http:/127.0.0.1:8000/api/items/yeasts",
              success: onSuccess,
              error: onError,
              context: self
            });
var onSuccess = function(data){
            alert("It worked!");
            alert(data);
            alert(self);
            console.log(data);
            // var this_data = data;
            this.yeast_options = data;
            return data;
        }
```

setting context property of ajax call to your viewmodel. so it is accessible in the success method.

Comment: oooo I see, I tried `var data = ...` with no success. thank you very much I will try this immediately